# 301 Redirect Still Happening even though its been removed

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am having trouble with some old 301 redirects.

They have been removed from the htaccess but still seem to be working.

Some of the redirects have been removed for over 1 year but they still redirect as if they are present.

Ive tried different browsers/private browsing, restarting apache, flusing caches on the cms system and no luck.

The 301s were set out like this

Redirect 301 /example.com http://www.example.com/new-url

Our CMS is magento

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have same redirects in Magento catalog rewrites (just a guess). Post your complete htaccess and give a real example of redirect. It can also be caused by custom varnish vcl (but very rare)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I managed to fix the issue. It was a duplicate htaccess in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by looking for other htaccess files in the ftp and found that an old htaccess had made its way into the root of the ftp which was conflicting with the correct one.

This was acting as a back up htaccess to the correct one and redirecting old URLS still.